# How can i release the memory of cvHaarDetectObjects?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
CvSeq* objects = cvHaarDetectObjects(
      &image,
      this->cascade,
      this->storage,
      scale,  // scale : Scale 1.3 means the next round scan will scale 30% bigger.
      2,      // neigbors : If objects less than 2-1, then the whole detection is invalid.
      0,      // flags : The only valid flag is 0 for now, means don't check the edges.
      cvSize(20, 20)  // min_size : The minium size of object.
    );
```

I'm using OpenCV for object detection, but i can't find any interface to release the objects' memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to release the cascade:

```
cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
```

to release the memstorage:

```
cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );
```

( all of it a good reason to use the c++ api instead , no ? )